# Modal pop-up form too big on iPhone

Tags: html, simplemodal

I have two Modal Forms on the same page.

One is an exact clone of the other. The first is `appointmentModal` and the second is `rentalModal`.

They both work perfectly on desktop, but only one works on iPhone.
The `rentalModal` opens too big or zoomed in, and it can't be scrolled.

How do I fix this? Both headers can be seen below.

```
<!-- Appointment Modal Start -->
<div class="modal fade" id="appointmentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="appointmentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="#" method="post" id="appointment-form" name="appointment-form">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_appointment_form"/>

                <!-- Modal header start -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="appointmentModalLabel">Book A Lesson</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal header end -->
```

The second modal:

```
<!-- RENTAL Modal Start -->
<div class="modal fade" id="rentalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="rentalModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="#" method="post" id="rental-form" name="rental-form">
                <input name="action" value="send_rental_form" type="hidden">

                <!-- RENTAL header start -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="rentalModalLabel">Rentals</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- RENTAL header end -->
```

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: try removing "modal-sm" from the rental modal - maybe it is preventing the modal from autosizing to the viewport size. The first modal doesn't have that class and works - and that is the only size difference between the two that I can see

Comment: Thanks, "modal-sm" wasn't the issue. I added that yesterday, while trying to resolve this issue, and forgot to remove it.

Comment: I don't know how to do a JSFiddle, but this is the link to the page http://vnd-ink.com/StillInNeed/index1.html

Comment: Click the "BOOK A LESSON" and "RENTALS" links to get to the modals. Both work on desktop, only "BOOK A LESSON" works on iPhone after "RENTALS" is clicked click the "RENTAL REQUEST FORM" button to see the issue (only an iOS issue) Thanks!

Comment: Hi - sorry I looked and still can't see the problem. I do have a question though - they both appear to gather the same information - with the difference being the first select list. Why dont you just have the one common modal, with a hidden input for the type (appointment / rental) for the form submission and create a function to show the correct select list at the top. Also - your id's for the second modal information (eg first_name. last_name.. are the same in each modal) so maybe you have styling in your css that is only being applied to the first one? I would go with a common modal though.

Comment: The form fields have not been customized yet! At this point, I am just trying the get the mechanics working. Having one appointment / rental modal is the last resort. It's just the RENTAL modal is too big on the iPhone. Both are sending the form data correctly. This is an Zoom issue only happening iOS, and only happening on the 2nd (RENTAL) modal! I don't know why one displays correctly on my iPhone, and the other is too big. Thanks for the input!